# Transform multivariate Gaussian into to multivariate t-distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, t-distribution

A multivariate t-distribution random variable $X \sim St(\mu_X, C_X, \nu_X) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be constructed as follows:

\begin{equation}
 X = \sqrt{\frac{u}{\nu_X}} Y + \mu_X
\end{equation}

where $u \sim \chi^2_{\nu_X}$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, C_X) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Can we construct a map $T$ that transforms $Y$ into $X$ without using $u$. In other words, can we find $T$ such that $X = T(Y)$?

Tank you for your help.

Comment: Bienvenue, Mathieu! Hit $Y$ with the normal quantile function, then hit the result of that with the cumulative distribution function of a t-distribution.

Comment: @JohnMadden, thank you for your answer. I am looking at the multivariate case so I can't use the trick of the CDF

Comment: May I recommend that you add this information to the body of your question?

Comment: @JohnMadden, thank you for your suggestion. I have clarified this point